# Cannot delete table starting with underscores

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera-cdh

I have a table named "__refactorlog" created by importing all tables from a RDBMS source using Sqoop. Since this table does not contain business data I'm trying to delete it now using:

```
DROP TABLE __refactorlog;
```

However, I get the following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 mismatched input ''__refactorlog'' expecting Identifier near 'table' in table name

I've checked that I'm in the correct database, that the table shows up normally using "show tables;", qualifying it with the db name and even quoting the table name, but I always get the same error.

The table is located in HDFS under /user/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/__refactorlog and it contains a small part-m-00000 file. I've also been able to delete other non-business tables without any issues, but they all had alfanumeric names.

Any idea how to delete the table (esp. the metadata, the HDFS files I can delete manually if needed)?

BTW, I'm using Hive 0.10 bundled in CDH 4.7.

Comment: Try using square brackets - [__refactorlog].  That works on other databases, not sure about yours.

Comment: No, square brackets don't do the trick. I get a mismatched input again, this time referred to the left bracket itself :-(

Comment: Try this "__refactorlog" or  '__refactorlog' or enclose _refactorlog with backquotes

Comment: The backquotes worked! Thank you very much @user2576028 !